# How to build Memgraph Docker Extension on Windows?

Tags: memgraphdb

I usually use Mac most of the time. Now I got one Windows 11 based desktop and on it I would need to build [Memgraph Docker Extension](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph-docker-extension/).

For some reason, I can't build it:

```
C:\Users\merkart\repositories> git clone https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph-docker-extension
Cloning into 'memgraph-docker-extension'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9736, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9736/9736), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6352/6352), done.
remote: Total 9736 (delta 3060), reused 9681 (delta 3028), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (9736/9736), 25.77 MiB | 9.31 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3060/3060), done.
Updating files: 100% (10382/10382), done.

C:\Users\merkart\repositories>cd memgraph-docker-extension

C:\Users\merkart\repositories\memgraph-docker-extension> make build-extension
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried to install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), but I also had no luck with the build process.

```
pacman -Syu --needed base-devel git mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl
```

What else could I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `make/cmake` you can use `docker build`.
I see that you have cloned the repo

```
git clone https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph-docker-extension.git
```

so just go to that folder and run:

```
docker build --tag=memgraph/memgraph-docker-extension:1.1.0 .
```

once build is done install the extension

```
docker extension install memgraph/memgraph-docker-extension:1.1.0
```

The tag, `1.1.0`, is not so important if you are doing a local build. It's only important to use the same tag both when you are building and installing extension.